# Python code confusion

Tags: python

im getting an Error in a Phyton programm I try to run that I dont realy understand, Help would be appreciated:

```
import hashlib, urlib, re
def convert2swissgrid(value, num1, num2, num3):
    return value * num1 + value + ( value / num2 ) - num3
web_domain = 'http://gc6ynbd.hikiashi.ch/'
web_page = '/index.html'
web_directory = hashlib.md5(raw_input('Please enter code: ')).hexdigest()
url = web_domain + web_directory + web_page
web_html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
web_body = str(re.findall('<body>((.|n)*)</body>', web_html)).split()    
hex_values, dec_values = list(), list()
for value in web_body:
    if re.search('^[0-9A-F]{,}[0-9A-F]$', value):
        hex_values.append(value[::-1])
        if  len(hex_values[-1]) > 2:
            dec_values.append(int(hex_values[-1], 6))            
north, east = 0, 0
for value in dec_values
north = north + value % 47
east = east + value % 8     
print "Norden:", convert2swissgrid(east, len(str(dec_values[4075]), len(str(dec_values[429])), dec_values[1838] - dec_values[134])
print "Osten:", convert2swissgrid(north, len(str(dec_values[54])), len(str(dec_values[1684])), dec_values[1732] - dec_values[2660])
```

The Error it shows me is in line 21, for value in dec_values
The message is:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax                                                                                                                                                                        sh-4.3$ python main.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "main.py", line 22                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    for value in dec_values
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: You need a colon at the end of a `for` line, and you need at least one indented line after it.

Comment: This line missing a colon (should be `for value in dec_values:`). The indentation of some of the lines below it is also wrong. How many lines? That depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: line `for value in dec_values` update with `for value in dec_values:`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
for value in dec_values:
    north = north + value % 47
    east = east + value % 8
```